# Set proxys to Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy, linux-mint

I already read several posts in here and none solved my problem.

When I open the chrome throw command line with:

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="my-proxy-server" --proxy-bypass-list="my-bypass-list"
```

All my proxys work perfectly. But if I save this configuration into `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and then open the application by its icon, the proxys won't work.

It's very stressfull to have to open the broswer throw command line and keep a terminal opened just to maintain it.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Is there some reason that the proxy settings in the Chrome UI don't work?  I mean, they are kind of hidden (all the way at the bottom, _after_ expanding the 'Advanced' section of the settings page), but unless you need to switch regularly, they should be sufficient.

Comment: In the UI i get this message: "
While running Chrome in a compatible computer environment, system proxy settings will be used. However, your system is not supported or has remained a problem when starting a system configuration."